# Using v-model and refs in a slot in Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that takes a main `<slot>` from a form that is generated elsewhere in my application. I'm trying to use v-model on the form inputs but my vue component just spits out a warning about the properties not being defined, when in fact they are.

I admit it's a weird way of doing things, but it seems to be the easiest way for me to do this since my form is being generated by Symfony.

html:

```
<my-component>
  <input ref="start" v-model="start"/>
</my-component>
```

my component:

```
<script>
   export default {
     data() {
       start: null
     },
     mounted() {
       console.log(this.$refs) // === {}; expected {"start":{...}}
     }
   }
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <slot/>
        ... other stuff here
    </div>
</template>
```

console log:

```
Property or method "start" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

I cannot use $refs or v-model in the  html. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `v-model="start"` in the parent then it belongs to the parent and needs to be declared there. It looks like instead you declare it in the component instead as `null`.

If you reorder things it should work as you expect:

Parent:

```
<parent>
  <input v-model="start" :start="start"/>
</parent>
<script>
 export default {
 data() {
   start: null // Important to define start here if it's used in this component's html
 }
}
</script>
```

Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot/>
    ... other stuff here
  </div>
</template>
<script>
 export default {
 props: ['start'], // Receive the prop from the parent
 data() {
 },
 mounted () {
   console.log(this.start) // Should echo the value of the prop from the parent
  }
}
</script>
```